# Reading a DropBox Text File

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I have an android app that loads images and text files into Dropbox. I've figured out the authentication and upload process.

Now, using the same authenticated session, I want to read one of the uploaded text files (to look for changes). I've found a download example, but that would mean writing it to local SD, then reading for there ... not efficient at all (in part because of the additional android permission required).

I've examined [Dropbox's v2 documentation](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/) and there do seem to be a bunch of read calls but I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to use them. The helpful [Android-Dropbox examples](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android) also don't seem to tackle my specific problem. I couldn't find any v2 examples on stackoverflow either.

Surely, somebody can point me to a simple example that provides a nice InputStream.

Comment: When you say "to look for changes" do you want to monitor the file for changes? If so you could try longpoll example https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/longpoll/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/longpoll/Main.java

Comment: @Searock. Interesting, but I'm looking for the contents within a specific text file that have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the Dropbox Java SDK `download` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#download-java.lang.String-) to get file contents directly. There's [an example of using that in the example app here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/DownloadFileTask.java#L69). That example writes directly to a `FileOutputStream`.

It sounds like you just want an `InputStream` though, which would look like this:

```
DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);

String remotePath = "/test.txt";  // the path to the file you want to download
InputStream fileInputStream = null;
try {
    fileInputStream = client.files().download(remotePath).getInputStream();
    // use `fileInputStream` as desired
} catch (DbxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much tooling around, here's something that works

```
    String my_link = null;
    URL my_url = null;
    URLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        my_link = my_DbxClient.files().getTemporaryLink("/" + my_File).getLink();
        my_url = new URL (my_link);
        conn = my_url.openConnection();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    } catch (DbxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```